# Pythonic way to split a line into groups of four words?

Tags: python, string

Suppose I have string that look like the following, of varying length, but with the number of "words" always equal to multiple of 4.

```
9c 75 5a 62 32 3b 3a fe 40 14 46 1c 6e d5 24 de
c6 11 17 cc 3d d7 99 f4 a1 3f 7f 4c
```

I would like to chop them into strings like  `9c 75 5a 62` and `32 3b 3a fe`

I could use a regex to match the exact format, but I wonder if there is a more straightforward way to do it, because regex seems like overkill for what should be a simple problem.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A staight-forward way of doing this is as follows:

```
wordlist = words.split()
for i in xrange(0, len(wordlist), 4):
    print ' '.join(wordlist[i:i+4])
```

If for some reason you can't make a list of all words (e.g. an infinite stream), you could do this:

```
from itertools import groupby, izip
words = (''.join(g) for k, g in groupby(words, ' '.__ne__) if k)
for g in izip(*[iter(words)] * 4):
    print ' '.join(g)
```

Disclaimer: I didn't come up with this pattern; I found it in a similar topic a while back. It arguably relies on an implementation detail, but it would be quite a bit more ugly when done in a different way.

Comment: This assumes that there are no spaces?

Answer (score 1):

A slightly functional way of doing it based on [itertools grouper recipe](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#recipes)

```
 for x in grouper(words.split(), 4):
    print ' '.join(x)
```

Comment: I do not see grouper in intertools.  Do you mean groupby?  Have you tried this?

Comment: @dansalmo, check the [recipe](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#recipes) section

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> words = '9c 75 5a 62 32 3b 3a fe 40 14 46 1c 6e d5 24 de'.split()
>>> [' '.join(words[i*4:i*4+4]) for i in range(len(words)/4)]
['9c 75 5a 62', '32 3b 3a fe', '40 14 46 1c', '6e d5 24 de']
```

or based on 1_CR's answer

```
from itertools import izip_longest

def grouper(iterable, n, fillvalue=None):
    "Collect data into fixed-length chunks or blocks"
    # grouper('ABCDEFG', 3, 'x') --> ABC DEF Gxx
    args = [iter(iterable)] * n
    return izip_longest(fillvalue=fillvalue, *args)

[' '.join(x) for x in grouper(words.split(), 4)]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
giantString= '9c 75 5a 62 32 3b 3a fe 40 14 46 1c 6e d5 24 de c6 11 17 cc 3d d7 99 f4 a1 3f 7f 4c'

splitGiant = giantString.split(' ')
stringHolders = []
for item in xrange(len(splitGiant)/4):
    stringHolders.append(splitGiant[item*4:item*4+4])

stringHolder2 = []

for item in stringHolders:
    stringHolder2.append(' '.join(item))

print stringHolder2
```

the most long convoluted way to do this possible.

Comment: why don't You use `xrange(0, len(splitGiant), 4)` this allows You to reduce calculation

Comment: because my brain is broken.

Comment: Just a little hint: Python (PEP8) encourages `underscore_style` over `camelCase`.

Comment: sorry @stretch_armstrong